# Convert C Define Macro to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c-preprocessor

How can I convert this C define macro to C#?

```
#define CMYK(c,m,y,k)       ((COLORREF)((((BYTE)(k)|((WORD)((BYTE)(y))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(m))<<16))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(c))<<24)))
```

I have been searching for a couple of days and have not been able to figure this out.  Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: Do you mean how can you pack 4 bytes in to one interger - or how can you create a C# Color struct from CMYK parameters?

Answer (score 5):

C# doesn't support #define macros. Your choices are a conversion function or a `COLORREF` class with a converting constructor.

```
public class CMYKConverter
{
    public static int ToCMYK(byte c, byte m, byte y, byte k)
    {
        return k | (y << 8) | (m << 16) | (c << 24);
    }
}

public class COLORREF
{
    int value;
    public COLORREF(byte c, byte m, byte y, byte k)
    {
        this.value = k | (y << 8) | (m << 16) | (c << 24);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's also worth noting that COLORREF is intended to be a 32 bit RGB value. not sure what this code is doing but it's not a standard method of converting CMYK to rgb. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426432/convert-rgb-color-to-cmyk

Answer (score 2):

C# does not support C/C++ like macros. There is no `#define` equivalent for function like expressions. You'll need to write this as an actual method of an object.